# 'User' object has no attribute 'image'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `image` on serializer `UserSerializer`.
    The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `User` instance.
    Original exception text was: 'User' object has no attribute 'image'. 
The problem is that I cant upload image to the userprofile model.Without the image field everything works fine.How can I make this right.

here is the models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    website = models.URLField(default='')
    phone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])


post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

this is the serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.validators import UniqueValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import UserProfile


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    description = serializers.CharField( required=False)
    city = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    mobile = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
    website = serializers.URLField(required=False)
    email = serializers.EmailField(
            required=True,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
            )
    username = serializers.CharField(
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
            )
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(validators=None,max_length=100, required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(validators=None, max_length=100, required=True)
    image = serializers.ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
                  'username',
                  'email',
                  'first_name',
                  'last_name',
                  'description',
                  'city',
                  'website',
                  'mobile',
                  'image',
                  'password',
                  ]

    def create(self, validated_data):

        profile_description = validated_data.pop('description')
        profile_city = validated_data.pop('city')
        profile_website = validated_data.pop('website')
        profile_phone = validated_data.pop('mobile')
        profile_image = validated_data.pop('image')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        user.userprofile.description = profile_description
        user.userprofile.city = profile_city
        user.userprofile.website = profile_website
        user.userprofile.phone = profile_phone
        user.userprofile.images = profile_image
        user.userprofile.save()
        return user
```

this is the views.py

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status,generics
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from accounts.api.serializers import UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import login,authenticate
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser,MultiPartParser,FormParser
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserCreate(APIView):
    """
    Creates the user.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data,)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            raw_password = serializer.validated_data.get('password')
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                json = serializer.data
                json['token'] = token.key
                user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
                login(request, user)
                return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this is the Traceback

```
Traceback:

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  480.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/accounts/api/views.py" in post
  22.             user = serializer.save()

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in save
  214.             self.instance = self.create(validated_data)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/accounts/api/serializers.py" in create
  45.         user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  415.         obj = self.model(**kwargs)

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __init__
  490.                             _setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])

File "/home/vishnu/Django/tutorial/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __set__
  430.                     self.related.related_model._meta.object_name,

Exception Type: ValueError at /users/api/users
Exception Value: Cannot assign "{'images': <InMemoryUploadedFile: image001.jpg (image/jpeg)>}": "User.userprofile" must be a "UserProfile" instance.
```

Comment: may be because it is `images` instead of image as per your model?

Comment: Can you add the traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Because Image is part of UserProfile, and not user.

Update your serializer's image field to this:

```
image = serializers.ImageField(source="userprofile.images")
```

This should help.

Comment: this and the edited answer produces error as    profile_image = validated_data.pop('userprofile')['image']
KeyError: 'image'

Comment: I dont see where you call this. in serializer's create? if so, validated_data does not have userprofile .

Comment: That was an answer suggested.I tried it and still produced the same error